# Associate Dog and Event to User

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I'm struggling with how to implement user associations with dogs and events in a dating site I'm developing. I want logged-in users to be able to view the dogs they own and events they've created.
Can anyone provide guidance on how to structure these associations effectively within my application?

This is what I have so far.

User's model

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, "First Name is required"],
            trim: true
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, "Last Name is required"],
            trim: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "Email is required"],
            unique: true,
        },
        passwordHash: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "HashPassword is required"],
            trim: true,
        },
        socialMedia: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Instagram', 'Meta', 'X', 'Linkedin']
        },
        birthday: {
            type: Date,
            required: [true, 'Age is required'],
        },
        address: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' },
        civilStatus: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['single', 'married', 'just for fun']
        },
        dogs: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Dog' }],
        events: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const User = model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Here's my dog model

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const dogSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Name is required."],
      trim: true,
    },
    picture: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Picture is required."],
      trim: true,
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "Age is required."],
    },
    breed: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Breed is required."],
    },
    civilStatus: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Status is required."],
      enum: ["single", "married", "looking to breed"],
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Size is required."],
      enum: ["big", "medium", "small"],
    },
    owner: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Dog = model("Dog", dogSchema);

module.exports = Dog;
```

These are the user's routers

```
router.get("/event/:eventId", async (req, res, next) => {
  const testing = req.params;

  console.log('id', testing);

  try {
    const userList = await User.find().populate('events');

    console.log('userList:', userList);

    res.status(200).json(userList);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

router.get("/dog/:dogId", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params)

  try {
    const userList = await User.find().populate("dogs");

    res.status(200).json(userList);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

[The output is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v39x5.png)

This is how i am displaying the user's dogs on the frontend.

```
const [dogs, setDogs] = useState([]);
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
        const fetchDogs = async () => {
            try {
                const dogResponse = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/dogs`);
                if (dogResponse.ok) {
                    const dogsData = await dogResponse.json();
                    setDogs(dogsData)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const userResponse = await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/users`);
                if (userResponse.ok) {
                    const usersData = await userResponse.json();
                    setUsers(usersData)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchDogs()
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
            fetchUsers()
        }, []);

        let userDogs = combineData(dogs, users)

        function combineData(dogs, users) {
            return dogs.map((dog) => {
                const owner = users.find((user) => user.id === dog.userId);
                return {...dog, owner};
            });
        }

        return (
            <>
            <div>
                    {userDogs.map((dog) => (
                            <DogCard  key={dog.name} {...dog} />
                    ))}
            </div>
            </>
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution i can provide is that you have to put your userId into the dogs and events collection, and not as now keep all the ids into the user (if a user create 1000 events you will have 1000 ids into your user, instead putting the userId into the event is simpler).

to do that add a field in both you schema:

```
userId: {
  type: Types.ObjectId
}
```

and now you can simple query you subschemas using that field.

if you want to archive the same result as now (using the virtuals) you have to use revert population, more info about that here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html section Populate.

Hope it will help solve tour problem

Comment: i am new to mongoose and i am trying to understand to associate the dog to user. I removed dogs and users from the user Schema. And I change owner to userId in both schemas. However, I am now getting an error :annot populate path `userId` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override

Comment: because you have to define a virtual field from the link i have attached (a virtual is a field that dosen't exist in the schema, so for example define a virtual called dogs and use the guide to get all the dogs with the current userId, in my opinion is one of the best thing of mongoose

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will use virtuals and learn more about it